# Install dotnet core issue

Tags: powershell, .net-core, server-core

I try to install dotnet core 2.1.4 on powershell using command like

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://download.microsoft.com/download/A/7/8/A78F1D25-8D5C-4411-B544-C7D527296D5E/dotnet-hosting-2.1.4-win.exe" -OutFile "dotnet-hosting-2.1.4-win.exe"
Start-Process "dotnet-hosting-2.1.4-win.exe" -Wait -ArgumentList '/S', '/v', '/qn' -passthru
Invoke-Expression "net stop was /y"
Invoke-Expression "net start w3svc"
```

After that, I try to use dotnet command, but it is not recognised.
Then I try to install it again as below.

```
Start-Process "dotnet-hosting-2.1.4-win.exe"
```

It pops up a dialog with three options. "Repair", "Uninstall" and "Close". I choose "Repair" and every thing works.

So is there any method that I can use to choose repair option with powershell process and don't need to click the button? Because we have so many servers, it's a disaster to login these servers and click manually.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Deploy the .NET Core runtime and your web app? Or just update the runtime? For one thing, you *don't* need to use `Start-Process` to run an executable in Powershell. You don't have to install the .NET Core runtime separately either - you could create a self-contained executable.

Comment: As for the `"Repair", "Uninstall" and "Close"` dialog box, this says that the runtime is already installed. You don't need to click on `Repair`. In fact, you shouldn't be using such code for deployment in the first place.

Comment: Or are you trying to deploy the *hosting bundle* ? Most likely you can specify silent execution eg with the `/silent` switch and a default operation like `/install`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,  I have updated script, Actually I deployed app firstly, then I found there is no dotnet core runtime, Then I try to install it. And if I have installed successfully the first time. Why it can not recognise dotnet cmd and the app act wirely. After I repair the dotnet instaillation, It works well